# Difference between JavaDstream & JavaReceiverInputDstream?

Tags: spark-streaming

What is the diffrence between `JavaDstream` and `JavaReceiverInputDstream` ??

I already tried both but, nothing different. Also, whether it affects the output of the function `print()`? because I saw from some source output generated from the twitter stream by using streaming spark, they simply show a set of batch with no log is blocking the output of public tweets. Examples of logs that blocks the output terminal is:

`INFO [JoBGenerator]`, `INFO [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher]` 
and so on. The whole terminal is filled with those logs INFO, and I can not see public tweets and exception clearly.

Next question is,

At first the twitter stream running properly (public tweets can be captured), but some time later the receiver did not receive a single tweet while the batch is still running well. So the conclusion is my system only accepts public tweets at the beginning of the running program and stop receiving tweets like forever..

Is there any spark file that contain log produced after running program? because i cant see the log clearly in the terminal..

Thx & Help me

Comment: im submiting spark using this command : spark-submit --class Streaming /target.jar

Answer (score 0):

**JavaReceiverInputDstream** - A Java-friendly interface to ReceiverInputDStream, the abstract class for defining any input stream that receives data over the network.

**JavaDstream** - A Java-friendly interface to DStream, the basic abstraction in Spark Streaming that represents a continuous stream of data. DStreams can either be created from live data (such as, data from TCP sockets, Kafka, Flume, etc.) or it can be generated by transforming existing DStreams using operations such as map, window. For operations applicable to key-value pair DStreams, see JavaPairDStream.

So the difference lies between ReceiverInputDStream and DStream. ReceiverInputDStream has method `getReceiver() - Gets the receiver object that will be sent to the worker nodes to receive data.`. We don't have this facilities in JavaDstream